# R code, importing fixed width files that need to be row binded, but have different widths

Tags: r, dataframe, fixed-width

Been working with some messy data. I have 72 files: 9 (CCLF1-CCLF9) tables split into 8 parts. Each file is a fixed width file and I have a dictionary of the proper widths and column names that I pull in from an excel spreadsheet.

Problem is, I realized after loading them, that there are files with an additional 11 characters. So this causes them to bind incorrectly.

What I want to do is search the file to see if it has the correct number of characters per line, and if so add 11 spaces in the correct location. I'll add a column name "random_11_spaces", then bind them together and delete the "random_11_spaces" columns.

For example CCLF1 file should have a width of 177, but 5 of its subfiles have a width of 188. I want to check to see if it equals 177, if so, add 11 characters, otherwise load the file.

I just don't know how to do that. Here's what I have so far to load in the data:

```
  # Pull in the CCLF Details xlsx and put them into a list
details_path <- paste0(mappingPath,"CCLF Dictionary.xlsx")
sheetnames <- excel_sheets(details_path)
CCLF_details <- lapply(sheetnames,read_excel, path = details_path)
names(CCLF_details) <- sheetnames

# Extract the column width and column labels vectors from the xlsx
widths <- unname(sapply(CCLF_details,'[[',"COLUMN_WIDTH", drop = FALSE))
correct_widths <- lapply(widths,sum)
col_labels <- unname(sapply(CCLF_details,'[[',"CLAIM_FIELD_LABEL", drop = FALSE))

# Set up group names for the CCLF Files (CCLF1-CCLF9)
CCLF_files <- paste("CCLF",seq(1:9),sep = "")


proc_files <- function(f, w, y) {

  # Get files with Current CCLF# in name
  files <- list.files(pattern = f)

  # Build a list of data tables from all CCLF# files and pull in the proper widths and column names
  df_list <- lapply(files, function(x) read_fwf(x, fwf_widths(widths = w, col_names = y ), na = c("","NA","~","1000-01-01","9999-12-31")))

  # Bind all of the CCLF# files into one main file
  df <- rbindlist(df_list, fill = TRUE)
}

# Create a list of all the CCLF Files
df_list <- Map(proc_files,CCLF_files,as.vector(widths),as.vector(col_labels))
```

Comment: You need to be looking at the information packet that CMS provides. The schema changes almost monthly on these CCLF files, and you're parsing script will need to be adjusted constantly to account.

Answer (score 0):

Vector operations are great when each operation is the same, but when there are 
exceptions I recommend a for loop. 
Something like this. The filenaming scheme confused me so fix the '...' areas

```
filenames <- ...   
for(i in 1:length(filenames)){
  data = ... read in filenames[i]
  num_characters = ... 
  if(num_characters == 177){
    ... fix the width ... 
    df_list[[i]] = data
  }else{
    df_list[[i]] = data
  }
}
df <- rbindlist(df_list, fill = TRUE)
```